# What's the most efficient and easiest way to parse block entities?

Tags: python, regex

I have dataset lines like:

```
"1234567 12345 123456789"
...
...
```

Each column has a specified block length i.e. the first one 8 "1234567 ", the second one 6 and the third one 9 chars and so on.

I can split them like:

```
line="1234567 12345 123456789"
datahash[0]=line[0:8]
datahash[1]=line[9:15]
datahash[2]=line[16:25]
```

But is this the most pythonic and efficient way?

Could I achieve this with regex? Would it be more efficient?

Comment: If you have specific block length, don't even think of using regex. Slicing is the best solution.

Comment: @nhahtdh: Why? Because it's cleaner or more efficient?

Comment: It's more efficient than regex, and you can avoid making subtle pitfalls with regex (i.e. are you sure the assumption is correct? are you sure the syntax doesn't introduce some hidden assumption?). Clean or not - I'll let others comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
sample = (
"1234567 12345 123456789",
"1234567 12345 123456789",
"1234567 12345 123456789",
"1234567 12345 123456789",
)

def slices_at(sequence,offsets=((0,7),(8,13),(14,25))):
  for line in sequence:
    yield tuple(line[x:y] for (x,y) in offsets)

result = list(slices_at(sample))
```

Yields:

```
>>> result
[('1234567', '12345', '123456789'), ('1234567', '12345', '123456789'), ('1234567', '12345', '123456789'), ('1234567', '12345', '123456789')]
```

---

Re-reading your question, I've realised that you want the terminating whitespace on the first two fields.

Here's a new function that takes a list of block lengths:

```
def slices_by_block_length(sequence,block_lengths=(8,6,9)):
  prev = 0
  offsets = []
  for length in block_lengths:
    offsets.append((prev,prev+length))
    prev += length
  for line in sequence:
    yield tuple(line[x:y] for (x,y) in offsets)
```

Yields:

```
[('1234567 ', '12345 ', '123456789'), ('1234567 ', '12345 ', '123456789'), ('1234567 ', '12345 ', '123456789'), ('1234567 ', '12345 ', '123456789')]
```

Comment: This does it as well. I think something similar will be my solution.

Comment: Yes. The function slices_by_block_length is my favourite. This is a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

You can also split on spaces. That way you will not be using the indexes but the solution will be still robust.

```
sample = ["1234567 12345 123456789",
"1234567 12345 123456789",
"1234567 12345 123456789",
"1234567 12345 123456789"]

def getValues(line):
    return line.split()

for line in sample:
    print getValues(line)
```

will yield the information you want.

Comment: Thank you. But I also wrote that I have a specified block length

Answer (score 0):

I favourited further solution:

```
def slice_by_block_length(self,s,block_lengths):

    arr=[]
    for i in range(len(block_lengths)):
        arr.append(s[sum(block_lengths[0:i]):sum(block_lengths[0:i+1])])
    return arr
```

calling:

```
linearr=myClass.slice_by_block_length(sequence,[8,6,9])
```